# Need help for Mongodb - Direct document update inside an array using "$pull" with vertx mongoclient

Tags: java, mongodb, vert.x

I got a tricky query to remove an element from sub-document inside an array. I came up with direct update query to do the action it works fine in command line.

```
Document: 

{
  "_id": "1234",
  "fruits": {
    "fruits": [
      {
        "fruitName": "appl",
        "state": "rotten",
        "colour": "red"
      },
      {
        "fruitName": "mango",
        "state": "good",
        "colour": "orange"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Query: working in cli and successfully remove the element from array.

db.getCollection('mycollection').update(
{'fruits.fruits.fruitName' : 'appl'},
{ $pull: { 'fruits.fruits': { 'state': 'rotten' } }},
{ multi: true }
);
```

How should I write the same query in vertx mongoclient or mongo java driver  ?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to take that cli query and transform it so that you can execute it with the vertx-mongo-driver. it looks like this:

```java
JsonObject query = new JsonObject().put("fruits.fruits.fruitName", "apple");
JsonObject update = new JsonObject().put("$pull",
  new JsonObject().put("fruits.fruits",
    new JsonObject().put("state","rotten")));
mongo.updateCollectionWithOptions("myCollection", query, update, new UpdateOptions().setMulti(true), res ->{
  if(res.succeeded()){
    //do something with the result
  }
});
```